# Codeigniter foreach displaying only one div

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

My table has got 4 categories with unique id. And all I am doing is just querying the database and including a foreach loop which is getting the cateogry ids based on which subcategories are being fetched. Since my table has got 4 categories . So running the loop has to return the div 4 times which I will echo out in the view. That is the concept I had. But it is returning only once. So the div `main_div` gets printed only for once. I don't understand what is wrong here.

In my Model

```
    public function getSubCategory(){

       $sub_div = null;


        $query_main_cat = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM main_category");

        foreach($query_main_cat->result_array() as $row){

        $mc_id = $row['id'];

        $query_get_sub = $this->db->get_where("sub_category", array('main_cat_id' => $mc_id));

        foreach ($query_get_sub->result_array() as $row_sub_cat) {

        $sub_cat_id = $row_sub_cat['id'];
        $sub_cat_name = $row_sub_cat['sub_name'];
        $sub_cat_mc_id = $row_sub_cat['main_cat_id'];

        $sub_div .= '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> 
                    <div class="table-responsive">          
                        <table class="table table-striped text-center">
                        <th class="text-center">'.$sub_cat_name.'</th>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
                          </tbody>
                        </table>   
                    </div>     

                 </div>';


        }

        $main_div = '<div class="tab-pane" id="tab'.$mc_id.'">

                    '.$sub_div.'

                    </div>';

       return $main_div;

       }

}
```

In my controller

```
     public function load_view(){

       $this->load->model("get_category");



       $data['sub_category'] = $this->get_category->getSubCategory();

       $this->load->view('index', $data);

    }
```

In view

```
       echo $sub_category;
```

This should return the div `main_div` 4 times. since I have got 4 rows in my table. But only is showing for once. Need some help here.

Answer (score 0):

You get only once hello, because you prematurely return out of the loop.

```
return "hello";
```

You should not use return in the loop, but accumulate the string and return it at the end.

```
$text = '';
foreach($query_main_cat->result_array() as $row){
     $text .= "hello";
}
return $text;
```

Comment: This is just the first step.. I have got again two foreach inside this one.. Are you telling me to do the same thing?

Comment: You have to understand what ' return ' does, and apply it to your code. If you want to return all the strings concatenated, you have to return them at the end.

Comment: It should be trivial for you to adapt my answer to your special case.

Comment: I tried your answer. What happening is, in your case 4 divs are showing. That's alright. But within each divs. the result of the `sub_div` is showing the previous result as well as the current result. For the first `main_div`, the `sub_div` is correct. Then from the second `main_div` onwards, it's showing the current `sub_div` as well as the previous ones. Hope I have made you understand what is actually happening.

Comment: Hey, that's really basic. You are courageous to dive into a framework. It's like reading Shakespeare before you know to read all letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Yes. I know I am doing something wrong. But I have to do this in Codeigniter. So, can you please point me out my mistakes? That will be helpful..